# How to get pygtk with python2.6 ? the update to 12.04 removes it. (cannot go python2.7 because of specific extensions)

Tags: 12.04, python, gtk

I have updated to the latest 12.04 and it removes the pygtk bindings for python2.6.

I've looked at the python-gtk package and it now installs only the lib for python2.7.

The problem is : I have an application that depends on gtk and python2.6 and I am sort of stuck : I cannot go to python2.7 and there is no package that install it for python2.6.

Note : I have the application source code dealing with gtk, so if necessary I can do the porting from gtk2 to gtk3 (gi.repository and stuff).

Comment: Why can't your program run under 2.7? Are you using features specific to 2.5 that have been removed? It should be easy to fix your code to work with 2.7 as well as 2.6 (and even python3 if you're willing to port to the GI bindings instead).

Comment: The code use Panda3d a game/3d engine that have bindings only for python2.6. It is a huge dependency and The binding method Panda3d is very specific. Without the proper knowledge, this would be a very long project.

Comment: Updating to the last version of Panda should help you.

Comment: Why ? The release note says nothing of python2.7, AFAICT the bindings are still for python2.6.

Comment: The features page for Panda says "All Python versions from about 2.4 to newest 2.x supported."

Answer (score 1):

I solved a same problem related python-httplib2.

below is that I try.

```
sudo apt-get source python-httplib2
cd python-httplib2-0.7.2/
sudo python2.6 setup.py install
```

maybe you can try with pygtk package.
I wish this will help you.